# How to show materials effects into Autodesk-Forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I am loading .rvt files into autodesk-forge viewer with some material effects like polish or satin and they display fine in Revit, but in autodesk-forge doesn't work. [img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey4En.png)

Is there any way to achieve this? maybe with another configuration in revit or autodesk-forge can't show this kind of effects?

Thanks u all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no straightforward way to render Revit models like this in Forge Viewer. The viewer *does* support high quality (PBR) materials and shaders, but it's up to the Model Derivative service to specify these materials when converting your designs. And as far as I know, the translation currently outputs PBR materials only for designs coming Fusion 360. Try going to https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io and look at the materials of the "Fusion Race Car" model.

Alternatively, you could apply custom shaders or materials to your Revit model inside Forge Viewer: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer.